# How to force refresh without cache in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Does Chrome have an equivalent to Firefox's Ctrl+F5 refresh? I can't seem to find one.

I changed my gravatar last night, and I can see the new one in Firefox after a Ctrl+F5 refresh, but Chrome seems to be stubbornly hanging on to the old Gravatar. I guess I could manually clear out the cache, but if there is a keyboard command to do it I'd like to know what it is (since it would be helpful for web development too).

Comment: CTR + R then CTRL + F5, once or twice - usually sorts the problem out. Or disable cache in Developer Tools -> Sprog (botom right) -> Network - Disable Cache.. reload the page and try disable that.

Comment: Great new feature added to Chrome for forcing a hard refresh - http://superuser.com/a/512833/92862

Comment: [Install the "Clear Cache Shortcut" extension.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-cache-shortcut/jnajhcakejgchhbjlchkfmdidgjefleg)

Answer (score 220, accepted):

[Chrome documentation](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=95743) states that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> should do "Reloads your current page, ignoring cached content. "

If it is not working, you can [file a bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list), but it looks like quite a few other people are having the same issue.

[Existing bug log on this issue] Closed as a duplicate, the issue remmains:

[[Issue: 94090](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=94090)]

Comment: Looks like it may be partly Gravatar's fault. In the header for my image, they are sending `Last-Modified: Fri, 20 Jun 2008 12:25:23 GMT`. I think this is either the date I uploaded my old Gravatar, or the date I signed up for Gravatar. The browser must be seeing that and thinking "oh, this new file has the same last-modification date, so I'll just use the cached one still." It's a bug if Chrome is doing that on a refresh ignoring cache, but it's a bug for Gravatar to send the wrong last-modification as well. I've contacted both parties. :)

Comment: @whitequark it seems necessary to do that step (Cmd+Shift+Delete on OSX) in order to clear the cached Flash XML.

Comment: I load scripts asynchronously from javascript, and Chrome seems to continue to use cached versions even after ctrl-f5, etc. Clearing the cache works. But another solution is to open an Incognito window (ctrl-shift-n), as it will Incognito mode will not use the cache.

Comment: Haha Chrome is super-cached, the only way I can overcome it is hitting Shift + F5 at least two times (really).

Comment: Chrome team should be embarrassed at such a bug sitting in the bug queue for over 2 years. I am very disappointed.

Comment: Great new feature added to Chrome for forcing a hard refresh - http://superuser.com/a/512833/92862

Comment: ctrl + r seemed to be the only one that worked for me (windows)

Comment: Definitely not working.  Chrome can just suck so badly some times.

Comment: Is this just not fixed in the official Google-Chrome or also not on the open source version?

Comment: @Tauren : Thank you so much for the incognito solution!  I cannot believe it is now nearing the end of 2013 and still this is a problem.  I just wasted nearly 2 hours trying to debug what appeared to be the most bizarre problem on my dynamic loading of javascripts.  I came here when I realized there was no way Chrome was using the live copy of one of them...

Comment: Scrap that, I can confirm 100% that incognito does use cached versions also. Argh!

Comment: @Alex I'm using Chromium and the bug seems present there as well (at least today).

Comment: @Psyrus, I agree, _even with Chromium_. :C

Comment: I'm having my issue with creating a gist, evaluating it on http://bl.ocks.org/, then updating the gist.  The update doesn't come through unless I manually delete the cache in chrome.  Does anyone else have a reproducible example?

Comment: Ctrl-F5... well try that with an iFrame you want to reload :/

Answer (score 224):

In the opened developer tools (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shft</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>):

1. Select the **Network** tab
2. Activate **Disable cache** check-box.
3. DO NOT CLOSE Developer tools - otherwise cache is re-enabled.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work for me, had to use incognito.

Comment: But why is there no short-cut key to trigger this!

Comment: Note the cache is only disabled while Developer Tools are open. If you close it, your cache is active again.

Comment: Even with activated **Disable cache** check box and open developer tools there still seems to be a difference between F5 and Shift+F5. An ajax call on my web page behaves differently, depending on the sort of refresh and I do not yet understand why.

Comment: In the newer developer tools (can be triggered by F12, too) the "Disable cache" setting can be found in the Network tab.

Comment: Welcome to the year 2019. The "Disable Cache" checkbox in the dev window still does not reload JS / CSS files.

Comment: This is very useful when the URL you see after the page has loaded is not the same you inserted, because there is a redirect in the cached page. When this happens you cannot force the cache with regular method (CTRL+F5)!

Answer (score 106):

On a Mac, it's Shift+Command+R, or holding down Shift while clicking the reload button (as opposed to Command+R or a normal click for a regular refresh).

Some more details:

For Shift+Command+R, cache is simply ignored and resources are requested like no cache existed.

For Command+R, Chrome will issue `If-Modified-Since` or `Etag` requests to the web server, *even for things that are actually cached*. For most, if not all, content the server should then respond with `304 Not Modified`. This is true for most, if not all, modern browsers.

The only way to force relying on the cache (without the browser even asking for possible changes) seems to be clicking a link on the web page, or by following a bookmarked link, or by going into the URL location bar and hitting Return there (Command+L, Return).

However: a longstanding known issue in Chrome, [Chrome Forced Refresh does not ignore cache](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=44122) (and the more recent [Reload/Refresh does not refresh](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=94090)), or maybe actually a feature in WebKit, [Dynamically inserted subresources aren't revalidated even when the containing document is reloaded](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=30862), makes Chrome not clear ALL related caches when using the above methods. A Chromium developer [explains](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=44122#c61):

> The network tab of the developer tools show a waterfall of all resources as they are loaded. There are two vertical lines at the right hand side... one of them is labeled "Load event fired" on hover. Anything loading after that point is not officially part of the page (a page can keep issuing requests for hours) [...] so it will NOT be "refreshed" with any combination of f5. This is by design.
>   [...]
>   Caching *[of any resource, before and after the "Load event fired" line]* is determined by the HTTP headers of the response, not by the time the request was issued.

Also [note a @ChromiumDev's tweet](https://twitter.com/ChromiumDev/status/227356682890670080):

> Chrome DevTools' Disable Cache invalidates the disk cache (great for developing!), but.. only while devtools is visible.

Comment: Thanks for the great detailed answer. Possibly too technical for the audience but I value it greatly.

Comment: Command-Shift-R is not working in current Chrome stable.

Comment: It seems to be working fine on my Mac, @olouv. Did you peek into the Developer Tool's Network tab? (True, on this very site there are a few resources for which Chrome still issues an `If-Modified-Since` request instead, but those resources are requested by JavaScript, not by the HTML parser. Also, as caching for the page itself is set to just one minute, maybe small differences in server time and local time might mess up too?)

Comment: **BEWARE**, note a two year old, but still current bug in Chrome: [Chrome Forced Refresh does not ignore cache](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=44122).

Answer (score 22):

## *UPDATE: This answer is outdated*

1. Pull up console
2. Click in right-bottom to cog icon
3. Tick [General > Disable cache]
4. Reload page (however)!
5. [Keep the developer tools open](https://twitter.com/ChromiumDev/status/227356682890670080) (UPDATE)

[image]

Comment: 5. [Keep the developer tools open](https://twitter.com/ChromiumDev/status/227356682890670080).

Comment: Great, in fact, even after i closed the devtool, it always clear cache.

Comment: This option is no longer in the console settings.

Comment: I rolled back my own edit, as this actually duplicates [Chris' March 2012 answer](https://superuser.com/questions/89809/how-to-force-refresh-without-cache-in-google-chrome/406331#406331). Please consider deleting this; you'll keep the reputation anyway.

Answer (score 19):

The question is a bit old, but in the recent version of Chrome

- Open the `Developer tools` using <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>
- Right-click the Refresh button, and select *Empty cache and Hard reload*

This will bypass the cache and reload the page fully.

The doc says <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> but unfortunately as of today the bug is still not solved :-(

Comment: Only works when Developer Tools are open, as you say Arjan.

Comment: You can also hold SHIFT while clicking the refresh button

Comment: @Arjan Just FYI as of 2020 this is definitely not Windows-only, as I see the same feature on my Ubuntu VM.

Comment: Also works on Edge Chromium (probably all Chrome based browers)

Answer (score 10):

I have files (images and full html pages) on the server that get updated and no key combination in chrome seems to force fetching them.

I rely on chrome´s incognito mode - CTRL-SHIFT-N - when I need to force refresh.

**Note** that CTRL-R or CTRL-F5 while inside an incognito window doesn´t seem to work either.  You must close and reopen the incognito window - hence my reliance on shortcuts - CTRL-W to close, CTRL-SHIFT-N to reopen.

Comment: You mean "re-open a incognito tab", not window, I suppose?

Comment: Interesting, for me CTRL-SHIFT-N opens a new window, not just a tab - is that not always the case?

Answer (score 6):

There definitely is no simple way to do this in Chrome like other browsers.  The documentation may say that CTRL+F5 or SHIFT+F5 should reload and ignore cache, but it simply doesn't.  I have a flash slideshow that stores the settings/configuration in an .xml file, and after updating the XML file, Chrome will still load the cached version unless I purge the cache.  I always have to run another browser when updating the slideshow so I don't have to clear my Chrome cache all the time.

Comment: Flash cache is something completely different from Chrome.

Comment: @Joshua Unless as this guy states, it works in other browsers but not Chrome. Don't forget Chrome comes with its *own* build of Flash player.

Comment: @CamiloMartin ... which also has its own separate cache. Wait... did you seriously respond to a post that's more than 2 years old? Ugh. I took the bait.

Comment: @Joshua Oh, you're right, I didn't realise :)

Answer (score 6):

Definitely a bug in Chrome - it's also images that should be changed, but it uses the old image instead, even after repeatedly hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>.

I was trying to change my Google Apps logo, but the only way it will change on Gmail is if I use incognito mode or clear the entire cache. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> keeps the old logo.

Answer (score 5):

Ctrl - Shift - Delete will allow you to remove cache for the previous hour. That will assure that the next time you reload a site it is fresh.

Answer (score 3):

I did this:  Right Click the FRAME (that was out of sync), and SHIFT clicked the "Reload Frame" option. The frame then refreshed properly.

Comment: Didn't work for me

Answer (score 3):

To clear the explicitly specified application cache navigating to `chrome://appcache-internals/` on chrome and removing the cache for specific web sites.