# Ctrl+F5 vs Ctrl+R (On Browsers)

Tags: browser

Is there a difference between these two shortcuts on most browsers?

Comment: My completely unresearched educated guess is that `Ctrl+F5` generally refreshes the page *without using cache* while `Ctrl+R` or plain `F5` refreshes the page *using cache as normal*.

Comment: Compare with <https://stackoverflow.com/a/59365277/38108>

Answer (score 58, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> [does](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306832) [indeed](https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Basic-Browsing/Keyboard-shortcuts-Perform-common-Firefox-tasks-quickly/ta-p/3866) do a force cache purge for that page, while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> does not.

Comment: so it is same as F5?

Comment: @Infestor, in Firefox F5 and Ctrl-R are the same. Ctrl-F5 and Ctrl-Shift-R are the same too. Of course, that's only one out of many browsers.

Comment: (As an aside: using F5/Ctrl-R might make a browser still ask the server *if* the content has changed by using If-Modified-Since headers, hence still leaving it up to the server to serve new content or not. Hitting Ctrl-L to get to the location bar and pressing Return, or selecting a bookmark makes most browsers rely on their cache without asking the server about any changes.)

Comment: @Arjan is this the same for Chrome? Like it is in FireFox?

Comment: Yes, @Kevdog777, you can check using the developer tools (Option+Command+I on a Mac, and then peek into the Network pane). But in case you're asking as you're having problems with Chrome's cache, then see [another answer](http://superuser.com/questions/89809/how-to-force-refresh-without-cache-in-google-chrome/278393#278393).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm on Windows. It is a keyboard shortcut on a program I was using, and by mistake, pressed it on Chrome, and the page just refreshed, so wanted to know what happened. :)