# What exactly does CTRL + F5 do?

Tags: browser, browser-cache

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ctrl+F5 vs Ctrl+R (On Browsers)](https://superuser.com/questions/205279/ctrlf5-vs-ctrlr-on-browsers)

What exactly does CTRL + F5? I have used for years to get fresh non-cache page. How does it work? Does it request makes a request to the DNS server for non-cache paged? If not, then when and where does it request for the non-cached page.

Comment: Related [Ctrl+F5 vs Ctrl+R (On Browsers)](http://superuser.com/questions/205279/ctrlf5-vs-ctrlr-on-browsers)

Answer (score 7):

It tells the browser to get a new page regardless of what it has cached on disk (As if you had never seen it before).

It has nothing to do with the web server.

Comment: It also has nothing to do with the DNS server. Your web browser caches (stores) to disk images, stylesheets and even much HTML content. Adding Ctrl tells the browser to ignore what it has saved locally and makes fresh requests for the main page and everything that the main page references.