# Keystroke to reload a page without cache in Chrome for OS X

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, browser-cache

According to the Chrome Docs, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> keystroke is only supported on Windows.

Is there any keystroke I can do to fully reload a page without the cache on Chrome for Mac?

Answer (score 48):

Just to be sure I always check 'disable cache' in the developer tools settings(icons bottom right when developer tools is open). That forces to reload the cache all the time when your console is open. When it is closed it uses the cache again.

I find <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> not reliable.

Comment: Michael thank you so much. I know, at these QA sites one should not say thank you. but this thing bugged me for weeks and its late here and i was annoyed and... thank you.

Comment: It's been 5 years but it seems cmd + shift + R is still not working on Chrome 58. [This article](https://www.technipages.com/google-chrome-how-to-completely-disable-cache) shows how to find the disable cache setting.

Comment: To clarify: on Chrome 66.0 and macOS, to disable browser cache (while DevTools are open), open your dev tools, focus/click on them -> press F1 (or just manually go to 'Settings' of devtools) -> Network section -> Disable cache (while DevTools are open)

Answer (score 20):

User reports in Chrome 17 the bug is resolved [bug report here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=44122) in Linux, and the other post [of the same request](https://superuser.com/questions/89809/how-to-force-refresh-without-cache-in-google-chrome) reports that <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> forces a reload. I wasn't however able to find a 'from chrome support' response, or a definitive supported example of this in action.

Hope this helps

Comment: I haven't actually found a reliable way to test whether cache is skipped when reloading – have you?

Comment: @slhck This answer is correct. `Cmd-Shift-R` or *View » Force Reload This Page* don't use the cache. Check in *View » Developer » Developer Tools*: No *304 Not Modified* when force reloading.

Comment: Just to point out, you don't see the `Force Reload` unless you hold down `Shift` while hovering over the menu.

Comment: The feature's currently broken for me in the developer version (19), so I thought I'd mention this here.

Comment: For the record this still does not ignore the cache as of Chrome 22, so I'm not sure "force reload" actually means "reload without cache".

Comment: I just checked: `Cmd-Shift-R` works in the current stable Chrome (version 26) -- no 304 responses.