# Clearing cache frequently in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, apache-http-server, xampp, internet-explorer-10, browser-cache

I am doing a project using Sencha extjs 4.1.1a. The Web Server I am using is Apache (XAMPP Control panel 3.1.0.3.1.0). 
I kept the project file in `htdocs` folder.

Now whenever I am changing the code in my project files, I am expecting some changes in the look of web page. Which is not happening in Google chrome. When I wasted so much of time, I realised that "Clearing the cache" will solve the problem.

Now the problem is, whenever I make even small changes, I need to "Clear the cache" of Google chrome. which is really annoying.

I am seeing changes in IE10 without clearing the cache. But as I love working with Chrome, I am asking here for support.

- Default Browser  -->  Google Chrome Version 25.0.1364.172 m

I just want to know: **Why google chrome is behaving such that I need to clear the cache frequently**? (Previously, I never cleared cache while testing my projects so frequently)

*This seems to be happening from the day when I updated my IE9 to IE10 through Windows Automatic Updates*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a workaround than a solution really, but you could just try `ctrl`+`F5` instead of simply refreshing the page (using `F5`).

This ignores the page saved in the cache and does a fresh `GET`. This should serve well enough as any changes made will be reflected in Chrome on doing so.

Comment: Nice one :) Thanks. But I am asking why I need to clear the cache frequently? (I was working without clearing the cache before).

Comment: @Mr_Green: I've observed that if the changes are small enough, the page is simply loaded from the cache. However as to "how small is small enough?" I couldn't really give you a good enough answer.

Comment: `ctrl` + `F5` is not working. I mean, not clearing the cache.

Comment: @Mr_Green: It should work. There have been [some issues](http://superuser.com/questions/89809/how-to-force-refresh-without-cache-in-google-chrome) with it in the past though. Or maybe try `shift`+`F5` as well.

Comment: @Mr_Green: On a side note, incorporating [this](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/reference/article.php/3472881/So-You-Dont-Want-To-Cache-Huh.htm) might help you.

Comment: @Mr_Green: Hi, I was looking up your problem and I stumbled upon [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576468/chrome-caching-like-a-mad-browser) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development). I thought they might help.

Comment: those questions are very much similar to my problem. Thanks for sharing those links. :)

Comment: There is a workaround, if chrome has cache on certain web page, you can right click on the reload icon and it'll show few options, choose either hard reload or reload and clean cache option

Comment: @Vishwa: Doesn't seem to work for me. Right-clicking on the reload button seems to be a NOP.

Comment: @RoneyMichael how about few quick CTRL+F5 s?   or you can limit storage option for local cache. thus resulting only less amount of recent items cache

Comment: @Vishwa: Ctrl+F5 is the original answer I had posted.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a widely popular free tools "Ccleaner" it can clear the cache in just few second it has many other feature which is very impressive for a 3MB size free application, and the best part is in Ccleaner you can delete all browsing stuffs like history and all other and you also have custom option to choose what you want to clear with Ccleaner
open ccleaner -> go to application -> below the google chrome -> tick in the check what you want to delete.
 [image]

Comment: This was not what I was looking for. I updated my post. Anyway, thanks for this info. :)