# How can you tell when the browser is retrieving from a cache?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, browser-cache

Is it possible to tell when a browser is retrieving a page from a cache?

I've thought that opening a new tab and directly browsing to the URL would make a fresh pull request from the server, but after testing (in which certain page tailorings weren't changing), it seems that this does not happen.

So is it possible to tell when a browser is pulling something from a cache versus pulling it straight from the web server?

Comment: In fact, *typing* a URL (or using favorites) often does *not* ask the server if cached content is still valid. Whereas refreshing a page often [makes a browser ask the server](http://superuser.com/questions/89809/how-to-force-refresh-without-cache-in-google-chrome/278393#278393), just to be sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way I usually tell is to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, or otherwise open the web debugging console, and watch the "Net" requests as the page loads. If you pay attention to the status codes, you'll see something like

> [15:15:26.059] GET http://www.example.com/index.html [HTTP/1.1 **304 Not Modified** 312ms]

when the cache is used, instead of the normal

> [15:15:26.059] GET http://www.example.com/index.html [HTTP/1.1 **200 OK** 31ms]

And if you want to be really sure that you're not using the cache, hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> when refreshing.

Comment: Or it might simply show "from cache" when clicking around rather than using a page refresh.

Comment: It doesn't quite work for json responses for some reason(with max-age rather than last modified headers) the only giveaway kind of is the response time there. Unless I am missing something