# web browsers are not picking up my web server via the hosts file, but they pick up my web server on 127.0.0.1

Tags: windows, networking, google-chrome, firefox, hosts-file

I run a web server e.g. `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80` or `python -m http.server 80`(which of those depends on python version),  and I do `echo blah >index.html`  to write an index.html with the text blah in it.

```
C:\Python27>start python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80


Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 80 ...
```

and it works

```
C:\Python27>curl 127.0.0.1
blah

C:\Python27>
```

Chrome picks it up

http://127.0.0.1  displays blah

My hosts file c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

has these lines

```
127.0.0.1 rice.com
127.0.0.1 www.rice.com
```

And the hosts file works, for rice.com

in that if I tell chrome to go to http://rice.com, then it says "This site can’t be reached rice.com refused to connect."

But it's not picking up the web server when going through the hosts file!

So I can access http://127.0.0.1 in chrome and that works

but when I do http://rice.com  it doesn't go to rice.com so the hosts file is doing something, or rather, it's having some effect.

but chrome doesn't get from http://rice.com to http://127.0.0.1

firefox also.

That was windows 7.  I tried it on another laptop that happens to be running windows 10, and same thing happens.

I start the web server  `python -m http.server 80`

And same thing.. If I do http://127.0.0.1 it sees it(contents of index.html). If I do http://rice.com then it says "site can't be reached. refused to connect".

Comment: I deleted my answer as regarding "Secure DNS", as it didn't help.

Comment: well actually a wrong answer or answer that doesn't help,  with some comments why, actually DOES help, because it is very relevant info relating to the question, that anybody else answering, or any other answers, can consider

Comment: OK, undeleted back. Hope it helps a bit.

Comment: @harrymc well, do you have any idea why what I found was kind of the reverse of what you thought it might be? (undersatnding these things can help)

Comment: Seems fishy. I notice that "Use secure DNS" is only enabled when Safe Browsing is set to Enhanced protection - try to set it to a lower Safe level. Mine is set to "No protection".

Comment: @barlop what happens if you use localhost and the machine's actual hostname?

Comment: @Albin  Well i'm not sure exactly what you are asking me to test there and why, though i'm familiar with the concept, If I do  `http://localhost` works(goes to my local web server), even though I don't have localhost mentioned in my hosts file. e.g. no `127.0.0.1 localhost` in the hosts file.  If I ping localhost then ping.exe tells me it's pinging {hostname}..and mentions the IPv6 address `::1` .  If I go to http://{hostname} then  that works too(goes to my local web server).

Comment: might be a problem with the configuration of your web server, does it allow for requests with a random URL in its current configuration? (remember the HTML request includes the URL of the host and since your client/host isn't part of the domain this might cause the webserver to refuse the connection). I think XAMPP accepts any URL in its default configuration if you want to try a different web server.

Answer (score 0):

If in `chrome://settings/security` the option "Use secure DNS" is enabled,
try to disable it and restart Chrome.

"Secure DNS" stands for "DNS over HTTPS" and is now enabled by
default.
It causes the browser to ignore all local DNS settings and do its own
DNS lookups using a provider configured in the browser
(by default probably Google) over a secure HTTPS channel.

This will prevent eavesdroppers or your ISP from tracking what sites
you visit by monitoring your DNS lookups, but it will also disable
your hosts file.

Comment: I will try that but as mentioned in the question, my hosts file is not being ignored

Comment: I tried it and things happen the other way around to what you mention(re whether the hosts file is ignored or not). i.e. When secure DNS is enabled, as it was, then the hosts file is not ignored. It refuses to load rice.com (the issue though is it doesn't load up my local web server). When I disable secure DNS, then it ignores my hosts file and just goes ahead and loads up rice.com

Comment: you mention that that you notice " that "Use secure DNS" is only enabled when Safe Browsing is set to Enhanced protection - try to set it to a lower Safe level. "  And you mention that yours is set to no protection. .    I notice that it is possible to be set to no protection and have secure dns to off.   Mine was on enhanced protection.   I just tried setting mine to no protection, and secure dns to off. , still same effects.

Comment: Very strange. I just added your two lines to my `hosts` file, and my Chrome has no difficulties reaching my IIS webserver via http://rice.com/. I don't know why this is not working for you, but try (1) Running Chrome in Incognito mode (no extensions), (2) Disable temporarily your security software and firewall, (3) Uninstall Chrome, clean up and re-install (save bookmarks). This might give us some more information.